# Rewind state machine back to a previous state

Tags: java, spring-boot, workflow, state-machine, spring-statemachine

Given an example state machine **S1->S2->S3->S4**, where these states correspond to web pages to be navigated using the **next** and **previous** events.

This models perfectly as a state machine.
How to implement random access/ad-hoc transition?

**Example:**
The user is at S4 and wants to go back to S2 (or any previous page of choice) and start navigating from there.

One idea is to use the persister to create snapshots at every state, then recreate the machine using the desired snapshot, which seems like a lot of work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem to specify in your StateMachine configuration that the transition from S4->S2 is possible on Event(X) and from S4 to any other state with Events Y,Z etc.

But you have to describe all possible transitions - that's one of the major benefits of SM - it's predictable and deterministic. You can't have "enable random/ad-hoc transitions - you have to manually describe all possible transitions.

So, do you really want to use a StateMachine to implement "free-for-all" web page flow?

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to force the state machine to reset at a certain state `S1` (already defined in your states configuration).
After defining the new state, you can resume the state machine from that point using the corresponding event.

keep in mind that this solution is for version >= `4.0.0`.

```java
stateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions( stateMachineAccess -> {
            stateMachineAccess.resetStateMachineReactively(
                    new DefaultStateMachineContext<>(States.S1, null, null, null, null, machineIdentifier)
            ).subscribe();
});
```

the `machineIdentifier` is the id of your state machine instance.
you can get it using: `String machineIdentifier = stateMachine.getId();`

For previous versions < `4.0.0` you can use:

```java
stateMachine.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions( stateMachineAccess -> {
            stateMachineAccess.resetStateMachine(
                    new DefaultStateMachineContext<>(States.S1, null, null, null, null, machineIdentifier)
            );
});
```